# Как исправить скролл на меню сайта?

Tags: wordpress, menu, elementor

Не скроллитсья меню на мобильном устройстве
Меню на элементоре

[image: попробуйте открыть меню на мобилке, при скролле меню не скроллится а сайт точнее блок скроллятся]

Мне нужен чтобы при нажатий на меню и при скролле меню, скроллился не сайт а меню
Запретить скролл сатй при открытий меню на мобилке

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfqO8.jpg): https://mimu-drop.com.ua/   ссылка на сайт

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужен чтобы при нажатий на меню и при скролле меню, скроллился не сайт а меню

Answer (score 1):

вы можете проверить состояние меню и отключать скролл когда оно открыто

```
jQuery('.elementor-menu-toggle').on('click', function(){
    let $menu = jQuery(this),
        $body = jQuery('body');

    if ( $menu.hasClass('elementor-active') ) {
        $body.css('overflow','hidden');
    } else {
        $body.css('overflow','unset');
    }
});
```